# Exchange 2010 hide contact from GAL, "All users" but not another address list?

Tags: exchange-2010

First the short version. How can I make a contact visable in an address list but not be in the GAL / "all users" Address List?

Now the detailed version.

The need. Organization with 7000 users. I have about 50 users (security guards) who only have iPhones provided to them by the organization. These folks don't have a desk, a laptop or desktops.  They can check their email from OWA if needed but we mostly want them using the iPhones. We want these 50 users to have access to contact information for about 70 high profile people, all normal members of the organization. Specifically the guards need the names, cell phone numbers and home phone numbers of the 70 users. At the same time we dont want the other 7000 users to see the cell / home phones.

To solve this needed the person that handled this before me created a user (Security-Guards), created the 70 contacts under this account, then mounted the account on the 50 iPhones.  It was done with scripts so it wasn't time consuming. The 50 guards also have their own mailboxes mounted. It works great but every now and then someone deletes one of the contacts the "shared" mailbox. Bottom line is its messy and needs to go.

One solution I thought of was to create 70 contacts (named differently to prevent confusing them with the users real AD account) with only the appropriate information needed for the guardschange custom attribute 15 to be "security". Create an address list in exchange only containing contacts with custom attribute 15 set to "security". Then an Address Policy allowing the 50 folks in security to see those contacts. This is great except I can't figure out how to allow these contacts to be in my custom address list but NOT in the GAL or "all users", "all contacts", etc.

I'm open to other solutions.. including making the current solution work.

Answer (score 1):

An ADP is the native solution. You would need two of them, one for the 7000 odd users and another for these small sub set of users.

Another solution though would be to use something like add2exchange from diditbetter to sync a public folder with the relevant information to the mailbox of these users. Set as a one way sync, if they deleted the contact then it would be recreated. However you would still have a central location to store the information.